# Send to the printer a javascript variable containing HTML code inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

Suppose I have a variable like this in JavaScript:

```
var h = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Example</h1><p>This is a variable I want to print to the printer with the browser!</p></body></html>"
```

How can I send the pretty rendered content of this variable to the printer?

I've tried:

```
var w = window.open();
```

and then:

```
$(w).html(h);
```

and then:

```
w.print();
```

But the thing is the Pop-up blocker blocks my new window with the printing page.

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you so much!

Comment: is the issue the variable containing the HTML or the pop-up blocker not allowing your new window?  Not sure I understand the issue so far.

Comment: My problem with that approach is the popup blocker. Maybe could exist some other approaches

Comment: +1 for everybody answering this question, and all are correct. My problem was, also, trying to "inject" html code with "<html>" and "<style>" tags also. By removing them and writing it to the source page with this CSS rules all went ok. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now normally I would not do this all inline.  But for the purpose of this question I felt it was easier to read this way.  Basically setup a media style sheet that allows a printable area.  then assign your html to that div.  Now when print is hit only the #printableArea will be sent to the printer.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #printableArea { display: none; }
      @media print
      {
        #non-printableArea { display: none; }
        #printableArea { display: block; }
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var h = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Example</h1><p>This is a variable I want to print to the printer with the browser!</p></body></html>";
        $("#printableArea").html(h.find("body").html());
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="printableArea"></div>
    <div id="non-printableArea"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This could be great but my variable contains all the <html> tags inside it and also the <style> tags too...

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to approach this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Fn2Yh/

```
var h = "<h1>Example</h1><p>This is a variable I want to print to the printer with the browser!</p>";
var d = $("<div>").addClass("print").html(h).appendTo("html");
window.print();
d.remove();

@media only print{
    body{
        display: none;   /*using @media will mess up the page if the user wants to*/
    }                    /*print the page normally. If that's the case you would  */
}                        /*want to set the display of the body to none manually.
```

By putting the content that is to be printed outside `body`, you can now simply hide the entire document, leaving the content you need displayed.

---

OOP: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/sLQzd/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a new window, you could add a special printing area to your webpage, which is only visible when printing.

http://jsfiddle.net/cp3zS/

**HTML**

```
<div class="non-printable">
    Foo
</div>

<div class="printable">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen {
    .printable { display: none;}
    .non-printable { display: block;}
}
@media print {
    .non-printable { display: none;}
    .printable { display: block;}
}
```

**JS**

```
var h = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Example</h1><p>This is a variable I want to print to the printer with the browser!</p></body></html>"

$('.printable').html(h);
window.print();
```